# Merging two overlapping NetCDF files

Tags: geotiff-tiff, netcdf, gdal-translate, gdal-merge, goes-16

I'm not an expert on this kind of stuff. Basically I'd like to merge two .nc files, one from GOES-R G16 and the other from GOES-R G17. The files contain the same variables and refer to the same time; they just cover different coordinates (but with some overlap).
To make things concrete, I'm talking about these two files:

https://noaa-goes16.s3.amazonaws.com/ABI-L2-DSRF/2022/219/16/OR_ABI-L2-DSRF-M6_G16_s20222191600205_e20222191609513_c20222191626275.nc

https://noaa-goes17.s3.amazonaws.com/ABI-L2-DSRF/2022/219/16/OR_ABI-L2-DSRF-M6_G17_s20222191600321_e20222191609388_c20222191623582.nc

The variable I'm interested in is DSR.

I tried converting both files to geoTIFF then merging, with the following commands:

```
gdal_translate -of GTiff "NETCDF:OR_ABI-L2-DSRF-M6_G16_s20222191600205_e20222191609513_c20222191626275.nc:DSR" g16.tif

gdal_translate -of GTiff "NETCDF:OR_ABI-L2-DSRF-M6_G17_s20222191600321_e20222191609388_c20222191623582.nc:DSR" g17.tif

# don't know what the following does for overlapping coordinates!
gdal_merge.py g16.tif g17.tif

gdal_translate -of netcdf out.tif out.nc
```

`out.nc` looks kinda right when plotted in panoply, but looking at the data I see that the latitudes have been inverted (in the original files, latitudes go from 81.25 to -81.25, in the merged nc they go from -81.25 to 81.25), and also values are much bigger (eg a value which was 124.4 in the original file is now 5435, 138.3 has become 6042, etc).

I'm a bit puzzled so I'm looking for confirmations, corrections or suggestions regarding the procedure I'm following. Perhaps there are better ways, but as I said I'm not familiar with this kind of data and the tools used to manage it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can actually use `gdal_merge.py` directly on your netcdf files. No need to convert to/from geoTIFF (also note that the order of the files is important, the first one will be written "on top of" the other in the overlapping areas):

```
gdal_merge.py -o out.nc "NETCDF:OR_ABI-L2-DSRF-M6_G16_s20222191600205_e20222191609513_c20222191626275.nc:DSR" "NETCDF:OR_ABI-L2-DSRF-M6_G17_s20222191600321_e20222191609388_c20222191623582.nc:DSR"
```

When you do this, you will indeed see that the values seem much larger and incorrect. Inspecting one of the input files with `gdalinfo`:

```
gdalinfo "NETCDF:OR_ABI-L2-DSRF-M6_G17_s20222191600321_e20222191609388_c20222191623582.nc:DSR"
```

Gives a lot of information, here is just the important part:

```
.
.
.
    Center      (-137.0000000,   0.0000000) (137d 0' 0.00"W,  0d 0' 0.01"N)
    Band 1 Block=180x180 Type=UInt16, ColorInterp=Undefined
      NoData Value=65535
      Unit Type: W m-2
      Offset: 0,   Scale:0.0228902790695429
      Metadata:
        add_offset=0
        ancillary_variables=DQF
.
.
.
```

`gdal_merge.py` removes some metadata from the output file (my guess is because it won't know what to do when the different files have different metadata values), including the, in this case, important `scale_factor`. We can re-add the scale factor to the `out.nc` file like this:

```
gdal_translate -a_scale 0.0228902790695429 out.nc out_scaled.nc
```

Now the values in `out_scaled.nc` match with those in the initial input files.